# Google Sheets - perform mathematical operations after extracting numeric data from strings with specific text

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**I need a formula that performs a specific mathematical operation, but only with the number that meets specific conditions. In this case – with numbers extracted from strings with specific text in them.**

In the first column we have some raw data: a string with different numbers and text divided by the underscore. I need to split this data into several different rows and use the following formula for this: =TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A3,"_"))

The next column should only contain numbers, but the problem is that one of these numbers (which contains "tb" in this specific example) should be divided or multiplied by the specific number (multiplied by 1000 in this case).

I've tried the following formula which only works as long as there is no "tb" or if it's in the very beginning of the string: =IF(REGEXMATCH(A6,"tb"),REGEXEXTRACT(A6,"(\d+)tb")*1000,REGEXEXTRACT(B6,"(\d+)"))

If it's somewhere in the middle or at the end of the string only the first number still undergoes the math operation instead. I wonder if there's a way to achieve the result I want without resorting to complex formulas (I'm very new to this and would ideally like to use formulas that I can understand and easily modify for other similar tasks). A sample table for better visualisation can be seen below. Thanks in advance!

| Raw data | Split data | Extracted numbers (what I get) | Desired outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5tb_200gb_300mb | 5tb | 5000 | 5000 |
|  | 200gb | 200 | 200 |
|  | 300mb | 300 | 300 |
|  |  |  |  |
| 2tb_500gb_50mb | 2tb | 2000 | 2000 |
|  | 500gb | 500 | 500 |
|  | 50mb | 50 | 50 |
|  |  |  |  |
| 500gb_50mb_2tb | 500gb | 2000 | 500 |
|  | 50mb | 50 | 50 |
|  | 2tb | 2 | 2000 |

Comment: is the actual question "turn the text string into a total amount of megabytes"?

Comment: No, that was just an example, no logic there. :)

I just want to extract all numbers as they are from most strings and multiply (divide, etc) from the ones containing some specific text - no need to sum them with other numbers.

Comment: here is a spreadsheet created specifically for this question, paste some of the real data and your expected output, and maybe folks will be able to help easier.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s78tIGvP-dlQm93OJTf7GtB73RfpU6q_WnyZEjiLh5Q/edit#gid=0

Comment: Please provide a real example and check your "Desired outcome" column. It looks like only the last `2tb` row turns into 2000? But what about the `5tb` in the first one? I thought that you just want to multiply the TBs by 1000 but that's not reflected in your outcome. If you check out [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM3YT.png) you'll see that by fixing the reference in the last `regexextract` you'll get the desired result of `tb=1000` but I'm not sure if that is your real intention or what your table really looks like.

Comment: @Daniel oops, my bad and thank you for pointing that out! There is indeed an error in my sample table (already fixed). And yes, I've tried your suggestions and it worked like a charm, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not putting `tb` in the first REGEXEXTRACT:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A6,"tb"),REGEXEXTRACT(A6,"(\d+)")*1000,REGEXEXTRACT(B6,"(\d+)"))
```

EDIT

Option 2: to extract the numbers adjacent before "tb"

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A6,"tb"),REGEXEXTRACT(A6,"(\d+)tb")*1000,REGEXEXTRACT(B6,"(\d+)"))
```

Comment: Works exactly same for me – no problem if "tb" goes first, but doesn't work as intended if it's somewhere in the middle, for example (multiplies the first number instead and doesn't multiply the value with the "tb" text).

Comment: It's probably the REGEXMATCH not working. If it returns the value without the multiplication is probably because REGEXMATCH returns False. Try uploading a realistic sample

Comment: @Oldy look at the edit to see if it works for you

Comment: thank you! It didn't work when I simply copy and pasted it, but then I checked the formula suggested by Daniel and it worked like a charm. It's basically the same solution you suggested, just needed to slightly adjust it – should be like this for this specific string: =IF(REGEXMATCH(B6,"tb"),REGEXEXTRACT(B6,"(\d+)tb")*1000,REGEXEXTRACT(B6,"(\d+)"))

Your answers were really helpful as well, much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, you were right, I tried it in another cell in my sample spreadsheet and it remained unchanged. I'm glad you could sort it out!